# How to get the currently processed dependencys artefactid during process-resources

Tags: maven, variables, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm looking for a way to get the artefactId and / or groupId of the dependency, that is currently processed during the process-resources phase.
What I'm trying to achieve is, that each dependency will be unpacked into a separate folder.
I know, that it's possible with multiple configurations, but i have to explicitly name each folder. 
(e.g. `<outputDirectory>..\artefacts\{$currentDependency.artefactId}</outputDirectory>`)
I want that in a more dynamic way, so that it's possibble to just add a dependency to my pom and i'm done.

Comment: Take look at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using.

Comment: The main problem is, that we're using the same artefactId for multiple dependencies.<br>Since I need this for building a setup which contains setups of our components, I get only one "setup.exe" for 4 artefacts (all of them have the artifactId "setup" with a "setup.exe" in a zip folder)<br><br>I know its scary, but different teams, different opinions, different solutions

Comment: Did you tried useRepositoryLayout=true?